# Executing Kiebase (instance retrieved from cache) takes more time to fire all rules as compared to when KieBase instance is retrieved from in-memory

Tags: drools, kie

On builiding knowledge base `KieBase` for the first time, we are storing its instance in cache so that we can save build time by using this cached instance. I noticed that when this instance is directly used x no. of times, it takes very very less time to fire all rules , BUT when we use cached instance then firing all rules takes more time.

Here is the time taken by `kieSession.fireAllRules()` when `KieBase` instance is taken from in-memory (i.e. `KieBase` instance is used directly)

```
min: 0 ms, max: 184 ms, avg: 7 ms  
Individual execution time: [184, 2, 15, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Here is the time taken by `kieSession.fireAllRules()` when `KieBase` instance is taken from cache (Redis) in each execution

```
min: 35 ms, max: 152 ms, avg: 51 ms  
Individual execution time:  [152, 42, 45, 51, 40, 79, 56, 42, 48, 42, 44, 44, 69, 38, 40, 39, 57, 40, 61, 53, 35, 41, 43, 45, 51, 43, 48, 41, 43, 60]

//NOTE: This does not include cache fetch time. It only reflects the time taken (in ms) by function `fireAllRules` of class `KieSession`.
```

In above example, I have taken very less no. of rules but in actual I have thousands of rules.

If you notice, the time taken is more when `KieBase` instance used is the one retrieved from Cache.

**What can be the reason for such behaviour? How do I make sure that the `KieBase` instance retrieved from Cache takes less time to fire all rules ?**

```
KieSession kieSession = kbase.newKieSession();
kieSession.insert(...);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.dispose();
```

Comment: How are you caching the Kiebase? Does your timing include the time it takes to retrieve the Kiebase from cache?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The above time does not include the cache fetch time. It only reflects the time taken by function 'fireAllRules' of class 'KieSession'. I am storing KieBase in cache in byte array form (using ByteArrayOutputStream, I have also tried using DroolsObjectOutputStream).  May be KieBase does some caching internally which is not serialized when it is stored in cache (just guessing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, KieBase serialization is not supported. Apart from performance, you may hit unexpected issues so please refrain from doing that (so I don't go deep why it's slow). You can store KieBase in-memory. If you have multiple nodes in a cluster, please build KieBase per JVM and store it in-memory per JVM.